# Continuous iPhone Integration testing server using Telerik TestStudio and Jenkins

Tags: iphone, ios, testing, continuous-integration, automated-tests

I'm currently writing an iPhone app and hosting my source on a BitBucket git repository.  I would like to setup a system for continuous integration on a spare mac mini I have in my office. I'm also using TestStudio from Telerik for running some automated test (I've created a dedicated target for producing a QA build which is visible by the TestStudio app on my iPhone or simulator).

To be precise the procedure I would like to automatise is:

```
1) download provisioning profile and certificate 
2) download source code
3) build the iPhone app using the TestStudio QA profile
4) running the simulator
5) start the TestStudio app
6) run the testStudio test
7) collect somehow the results
8) [this is just a bonus] inform me if there was an error in any of the test
```

I was thinking to use Jenkings together with TestStudio,but I definitely need some console tricks for performing more of the operation I mentioned.

Any suggestion is more than welcome.

Thanks
Claudio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I did:

1. In Jenkins, install the Xcode plugin
2. Whilst you're there install the git and github plugins
3. Create a new Jenkins job

a) Add the git URL (you may need to set up a github Deploy key)

b) Add an Xcode build step - check "Clean before Build" and "Build IPA"

More advanced: you may want to add a Github Post Receive hook to notify Jenkins of a push to github so that it triggers a build.

Comment: Thanks! I've also found a good procedure here.
http://chrisboyddotnet.blogspot.co.uk/2011/10/github-jenkins-testflight-part-2.html